# Installing TYPO3 8.7 on domainfactory

Tags: typo3

Domainfactory does not allow symlinks to files - so i can make the symlinks to typo3_src and typo3_src/typo3 but not to typo3_src/index.php. In oder TYPO3-Version it was possible to copy the index.php in the webroot and all worked. In TYPO3 8.7 this is not possible anymore. Does anybody know how i could install TYPO3 without this missing smylink? Or does anybody successfully install TYPO3 8.7 on a domainfactory server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was my fault - I took the wrong index.php. There are two of them in the typo3 folder: one in the root and one in subfolder /typo3/ ... of course one is for the frontend and one for the backend. I know this exactly, but nevertheless i took the wrong one ... outch. :-) Perhaps it was too late yesterday. Very thanks for your help, and sorry about the noise ...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a DomainFactory Managed Server, you can activate FastCGI in the PHP settings. In this case, you can use Symlinks for the index.php.

FastCGI is great to have Symlinks for files available. Drawback is, that you can't switch the PHP version via .htaccess setting e.g. `AddType application/x-httpd-php7 .php`.

In Shared Hosting, FastCGI is not available. Thus you need to copy the index.php from typo3_src to the web root as already described here.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 8.7 works on my domainfactory Managed Hosting Professional. I just copy the index.html file to webroot. Do you have the correct php version?

Comment: I think you mean to copy the index.php file.

Comment: hm, yes, i did the same ... and the install tool said it is the correct version of php.

Comment: Yeah of course, the index.php. What is the error message?